# How do I list all stored procedures in Informix?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix

I'm looking for a way to list all the stored procedures in my database running on Informix.

Is there a table in the `"informix".*` database that lists stored procedures along with detail information about them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called `sysprocedures`. Try this to see all there's to see:

```
select * from sysprocedures
```

For more information on what detailed information is available, read about [sysprocedures](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqlr.doc%2Fids_sqr_053.htm) and [sysprocbody](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_051.htm) and [sysproccolumns](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_052.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Get the procid of the stored procedure from the below query

*select sysprocedures.procname,sysprocedures.procid  from sysprocedures*

and provide the procid in the below query to view the whole stored procedure

*select data
 from sysprocbody
 where procid = @procid
 and datakey = 'T'
 order by seqno*

Comment: This is great, thankyou. Would you know how to execute said procedure?

Comment: To answer my above comment:
call <procname>()

Comment: God bless you, I've been looking for it all the day.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sysprocedures.procname from sysprocedures;
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question using the information I provided in my answer??

Comment: mouse over the time stamps; his answer was first

Comment: @Adrian - I found the answer on google and posted before i saw yours, but jeff, i think Adrian posted a minute before me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of the stored procedures (the text) with dbschema:
dbschema -d  -f all
or 
dbschema -d  -f

The text of the procedure is also in the sysprocbody table "where datakey='T'"

so:
    select data from sysprocbody
    where procid in (select procid from sysprocedures where
    procname='')
    and datakey='T'
    order by seqno;
  -- Note that in older Informix, this would complain that seqno had to be included in the list of selected columns.