# Informix: using stored procedures in Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, informix

how can I find the parameters(function declaration) of stored procedures in Informix? 
whether "{ call sp_csq_activity }" or "{ call sp_csq_activity(?,? ..) }" and their types? And also is there any definitions list of this stored functions? How can I use these functions to retrieve any columns of a table in db?

```
public void callSP() throws SQLException {

        CallableStatement proc = null;

        proc = conn.prepareCall("{ call sp_csq_activity }");
        proc.execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this : `select * from sysprocedures`

As explained in this post : [How do I list all stored procedures in Informix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958886/how-do-i-list-all-stored-procedures-in-informix)

Comment: I read that post but it does not give any parameters list just procedure body. I need functions declarations that contains parameters and returns value.

Comment: Have you checked sysprocedures and sysprocbody and sysproccolumns as well, as explained in the first answer?

Comment: It is my fault. I forgot to look sysproccolumns. Thanx for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to get the information you want.

A simple program that gets all stored procedures and their parameters is this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName ("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:informix-sqli://.........");

            ResultSet rsProcs;

            DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = conn.getMetaData();

            rsProcs = dbMeta.getProcedures(null, null, null);

            while (rsProcs.next()) {
                String procName = rsProcs.getString("PROCEDURE_NAME");
                System.out.println(procName);

                ResultSet rsParams = dbMeta.getProcedureColumns(null, null, procName, null);

                while (rsParams.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Param " + rsParams.getString("ORDINAL_POSITION") + " :" +
                            " Name: " + rsParams.getString("COLUMN_NAME") +
                            " Type: " + rsParams.getString("COLUMN_TYPE") + 
                            " Data Type: " + rsParams.getString("DATA_TYPE"));
                }
                System.out.println("");

                rsParams.close();
            }
            rsProcs.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Check the java.sql.Types section at [Constant Field Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql) for the SQL data type values.