# How do I list all functions in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix, information-schema

I'm looking for a way to list all the user-defined functions in my database running on Informix.

Is there a table in the "informix".* database that lists functions along with detail information about them?

Note: this question is deliberately very similar to [How do I list all stored procedures in Informix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958886/how-do-i-list-all-stored-procedures-in-informix) but applies to **functions** and not procedures.

Comment: There is the column `isproc` on the `sysprocedures` catalog table.The online documentation gives a bit more detail [SYSPROCEDURES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_053.htm).

Comment: @LuísMarques That looks like an excellent start! Could you move this to an answer along with how to restrict this to user-defined ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `sysprocedures` catalog table you can filter for non `procedure`SPLs:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sysprocedures
WHERE
    isproc = 'f';
```

[SYSPROCEDURES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_053.htm)

[Review information about user-defined routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.udr.doc/ids_udr_125.htm)

However, I am not aware of an exact way to determine if a function is user defined.

You could look to the `owner` of the function, but if it was created with the user `informix` then it can no longer be distinguished from the system functions.

The other catalog tables related to functions also do not seem to contain enough information to help:

```
SYSPROCAUTH
SYSPROCBODY
SYSPROCCOLUMNS
SYSPROCPLAN
SYSROUTINELANGS
```

Reading a bit more into the documentation, it seems that a lower case value `mode` column indicates a `protected` (system) routine . So the routines that are of interest are the ones with modes `O`, `R`, `D` and `T` (all uppercase).

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sysprocedures
WHERE
    isproc = 'f'
    AND mode IN ('O', 'R', 'D', 'T');
```

However, this does not guarantee that the routine is user created. In the `sysadmin` there are routines marked with mode `O` that were created by the system.

Also if you, for example, in Informix version 12.10.FC10, use the a regex routine, the system automatically registers the regex datablade and the corresponding support routines are created with mode `O` .

```
EXECUTE FUNCTION regex_match ('Regex module' , '[Mm]odule|DataBlade');

SELECT * FROM sysprocedures WHERE procname= 'regex_match';

procname        regex_match
owner           informix
procid          568
mode            O
retsize         200
symsize         813
datasize        0
codesize        0
numargs         4
isproc          f
specificname
externalname    $INFORMIXDIR/extend/ifxregex.1.00/ifxregex.bld(ifxregex_match_c
                har)
paramstyle      I
langid          1
paramtypes      lvarchar,lvarchar,integer,integer
variant         f
client          f
handlesnulls    t
iterator        f
percallcost     1000
commutator
negator
selfunc
internal        f
class
stack
parallelizable  t
costfunc
selconst        0.00
collation       en_US.819
procflags       0
```

So, system created, but with mode `O`.

Comment: `mode='O'` seems to help for determining whether it is user-defined

Comment: Yes, it helps. After reading the documentation and doing some simple testing it seems that lower case modes indicate `protected` (system) routines. I will add that to my answer.